# Castle Windsor's Resolve Caching Issue

Tags: castle-windsor

The WindsorContainer::Resolve method doesn't seem to be paying close enough attention to the arguments I'm using.  That, or it's doing some caching and not resolving the second time.

I have `ILogger`, which isn't important to see, and a single implementation of it:

```
public class log4netLogger : ILogger
{
    private log4net.ILog _logger;

    public log4netLogger(string name)
    {
        _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(name);
    }

    public log4netLogger(Type type)
    {
        _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(type);
    }

    // ...
}
```

And I have the following code that resolves ILogger from configuration:

```
WindsorContainer c = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
var a = c.Resolve<ILogger>(new { name = "asdf" });
var b = c.Resolve<ILogger>(new { type = typeof(int) });
```

When `a` is assigned, the first constructor is used... when `b` is assigned, neither constructor is used and `a == b` is true.  If I reverse the order and assign `b` first, the 2nd constructor will be used and the instances of ILogger will still be identical.

Do I have to do something extra for it to pay closer attention to parameters (in the config perhaps), or am I just totally doing wrong?

Config looks like:

```
<component id="Logger"
           type="namespace.log4netLogger, assembly"
           service="namespace.ILogger, assembly"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Everything works as expected](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.LifeStyles.ashx).

Comment: yeap. That's probably what you were after.